# Can a PHP class declare its attributes dynamically?

Tags: php, oop, class, if-statement, attributes

Usually when I write a PHP class I have done something like this:

```
class MyClass () {
   public attribute1;
   public attribute2;
   public attribute3;
}
```

Is it possible to set attributes based on logic?

```
class MyClass () {

   public function __construct() {
      if (some condition) {
         public attribute1;
         attribute1 = 23;
      } else {
         public attribute1;
         attribute1 = 55;
         public attribute2;
         attribute2 = 11;        
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is possible, however perhaps it would be better if you described how you intend to use this class.  Some scenarios would suit prototyping, others would be better with multiple classes, and some even by utilizing inheritance.

Comment: If you truly have different types of `MyClass` that need different properties, you might best use inheritance you have a base `MyClass` and than extend with subclasses for different property needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like others said, use `$this->param = 11;`, but I don't like this idea, because **I don't like undeclared variables** in my classes.

Declaring variables in a class definition is for readability, and you can set private, public and protected. In java this is not permitted, and so should be in php, **it should be error**.

If your don not know what variables you will use, **use magic methods** [_*get()*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).

### Example code:

```
class MyClass {

    private $store = [];

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return isset($this->store[$name]) ? $this->store[$name] : null; # or output error
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->store[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (rand(0,1)) {
            $this->attribute1 = 12;
        } else {
            $this->attribute2 = 21;
        }
    }

}

var_dump( (new MyClass)->attribute1 );
var_dump( (new MyClass)->attribute1 );
var_dump( (new MyClass)->attribute1 );
```

### Output:

```
int(12)
NULL
int(12)
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: Wow, didn't had realised that you couldn't set the visibilities that way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you do it like this:

```
class MyClass () { 

   public function __construct() { 
      if (some condition) { 
         $this->attribute1 = 23; 
      } else { 
         $this->attribute1 = 55; 
         $this->attribute2 = 11;         
      } 
   } 
}
```

and the attributes will always be public.

Answer (score 2):

An attribute is created when it's first accessed. As others said, it's not seen as a good practice, it's called *monkey patching*, and is only possible in dynamic languages (ie those where a compiler is not involved, at least on the developer side).

It's not good practice because if you don't keep your fields in a centralized place, automatic generation tools won't work, code assistants may not work, and other contributors to the codebase may have troubles understanding your code.

However it's not **always** a bad practice. For example, CakePHP (an MVC framework) uses the following technique to speed up the writing of certain classes. When you extend the `Controller` class like this

```php
class ThingsController extends AppController {

  var $components = array("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");

  function index() {
    $this->Foo($this->Bar->bar());
  }

}
```

the `$components` variable is examined by the base class constructor to dinamically load the `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` classes, and make them automagically available in instance variables like `$this->Foo` inside `ThingsController`. However this is clearly stated in the documentation, and is a convention thoroughly used in modern frameworks to provide *magic variables*, ie variables not directly declared in code. This usage saves typing, but comes at the price of breaking support from the aforementioned tools - not to say that new developers often have some headaches :P

Comment: +1 for giving reasons why it's not good practise, as well as identifying an example of the rare exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Properties which do not exist are created when first called.

```
class MyClass () {

   public function __construct() {
      if (some condition) {
         $this->attribute1 = 23;
      } else {
         $this->attribute1 = 55;
         $this->attribute2 = 11;        
      }
   }
}
```

But doing so is not a good practice. This way you will have to search for the properties declaration *anywhere* in your project. Think about your teammates(if any) or your future self. You should define all the properties the class has explicitly or you will definitely forget where you define them.

Comment: Thanks kgb, does this mean objects do not generally vary their properties?

Comment: Vary? I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: In the example above, sometimes the class will have 1 attribute, and sometimes it will have 2. If I explicitly define the attributes, how could the class sometimes have just attribute1, and sometimes both attributes?

Comment: @Donny P - with the exception of certain specialist classes (such as ORM) it's generally better to explicitly define the attributes appropriate to your class... and just because an attribute is defined, it can still have a NULL value if you don't use it in certain instances of your class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you wouldn't use `public attribute1;'` inside a method though. You would use `$this->attribute1 = 23;` or `$this->attribute2 = 11;`

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

```
class MyClass () {
   public $attribute1;

   public function __construct($an_array = NULL) {
      if ($an_array) {
         $this->attribute1 = $an_array;  
      }
   }
}
```